# Find out map path from user account to Security group[Win server 2012]

Tags: security, authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have system account which is part of a security group. the account is added to SG indirectly. How can i find the map path between the user account and Security  group

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related to programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly than with this powershell script:
Effective AD Group Membership
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Effective-AD-Group-b4759085